# Keep structure of navbar when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple navigation bar using html and css. The issue with it is when zoomed in, the structure changes as not all the links can fit in one line. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/b3Lw4/

Here is the code in case you are unable to access jsfiddle:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li class="nav" id="order"><a href="#">ORDER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navBar {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:0.1em;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

.nav {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    border-left:3px solid;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
}

.nav a:hover{
border-bottom:3px solid;
}

#order {
    float:right;
    color:#E65C00;
}
```

I have tried various ways, none to any success. One way I am wondering about is if I can edit it so that it will flow off the page if it doesn't fit (so only part of the width of the navbar is seen at one time), but I can't seem to work my head around it. Another way I think would be to detect the screen width/zoom and change the structure completely if the available space is too small, but I am unsure if this is possible (I've looked into it, but have not found any that seem to work the way I've described.

Just in case it helps: one thing I have spotted is the floats may be preventing me from being able to fix this.

Are there any ways to fix this and if so, how? I don't mind how it works (eg. flows off the screen or zooms the whole navbar out) so long as it does work. I've been stuck on this for three days now (I'm still new to it all) so any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution (it may not be of use to everyone who sees this, but is one alternative solution to the issue). I put the li element that floats right in a separate div so that when zoomed in it will not drop below the others or overlap. Instead the other li elements will drop down before they overlap, whilst still working properly.

From the HTML, the #order element (float right) is in a div before the other li elements put into a new div.

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav" id="order"><a href="#">ORDER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/3pd5Z/#base

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because float is considering a 100% width for the navbar. Add a width in pixels to fix the size of the navbar, like this

```
#navBar {
    width: 550px;
}
```

Although this will cause elements to flow out of current window (and hence bringing the scrollbar). Your best bet in such a case is make stuff responsive and create different styles for different widths.

Comment: Is there any particular width I should set it at? I tried it and 540 is slightly too small as the order link drops slightly below the rest as it doesn't quite fit, but making it too big would surely make it too wide for some narrow screens?

Comment: You have to experiment and try to find the perfect width. I think having around 545-550 should be good. Try in the console before adding to code to make the fast.

Comment: When the page is loaded, does the width of the page automatically fit the screen width, therefore the pixel width is used as a method of proportionality? I might be unclear, but what I mean is if you set the width to idk 540px, then something at 270px width will just take up half the screen no matter what the actual screen size is?

Comment: No actually, width of an element depends on its constituents. If constituents can fit in less than width of window, it will try to do that. But it will never, unless specified, make constituents flow beyond current window (Unless you specify positions for each element, which will cause further problems). 
Also, don't try to confuse screen size with pixels. A screen can have resolution of 1366x768 too and 640x480 too. 240 may be half size for a 640x480 but not for a 1366x768.

Answer (score 1):

When you zoom into the page, the size of the viewport is decreasing.
That means you can use media queries to create proper breakpoints:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #navBar {
        font-size:5px;
    }
}
```

The 600px mark works well in my test case. But you can't reproduce it via jsfiddle. 5px aren't too small since you're zoomed in. The best approach however would be using em values instead of px since they allow to change the reference font-size: `body { font-size:0.9em; }`. This will be inherited by any other element.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it kind of works, however won't it need to be different depending on the screen size other people are using?

Comment: I have looked/experimented with css media queries following this answer, however I still can't get it to work... I guess I'll keep trying, The problem I've found with yours is that it works to a point, but zooming in further causes the problem again. Any further feedback/advice on this? Thanks.